# plays multiple wav files at same time, for drum machine in Python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, pydub

I would like to play different wav files with different length "same time" independently from each other like a real drum set.

I found different libraries for audio control such as PyAudio, Pydub.. etc and i think the solve of this problem is threading.. but it doesn't play sound at all

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import thread

def play_sound(f_directory,f_file):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(f_directory+f_file)
    play(audio)

thread.start_new_thread(play_sound,("drum samples/","ride_crash.wav"))
thread.start_new_thread(play_sound,("drum samples/","crash_hi.wav"))
thread.start_new_thread(play_sound,("drum samples/","kick.wav"))
```

if i modify this code to this

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import thread

def play_sound(f_directory,f_file):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(f_directory+f_file)
    play(audio)

thread.start_new_thread(play_sound("drum samples/","ride_crash.wav"))
thread.start_new_thread(play_sound("drum samples/","crash_hi.wav"))
thread.start_new_thread(play_sound("drum samples/","kick.wav"))
```

It plays only the first one.

The reason i used PyDub instead of PyAudio is i think the use of PyDub is lot easier, but maybe useless for this situation. I also used overlay, but the problem with that, it is played all the files only for the duration of the first file.

I would like to know, what is the problem or please, let me know if there is a better solution, maybe another library, but if it possible i would like to avoid PyGame or Pyglet etc... because i think this will slow my program. If not, i look forward to it.

Comment: pydub's playback uses pyaudio when available and ffplay as a fallback. Both are intended for a quick-and-easy debugging use, though the [pyaudio mechanism](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py#L22) _could_ be extended for production use (I promise, you don't want ffplay for anything real). Basically you'd just make the chunks much smaller (like 10ms if that's an acceptable amount of latency. It probably is) and combine all the currently playing audio signals 10ms at a time before writing to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is not the solution because as far as I know all playback methods that PyDub uses are limited to a single stream only

I'm afraid you'll need to use a more lowlevel api after all, that lets you open multiple audio channels at the same time. Perhaps you can do it with pyaudio yourself by opening multiple streams from the same Pyaudio context

I've taken a different route myself; I'm mixing all samples together into a single resulting output sample that is played over a single output stream.

Comment: So i should open different streams for each drum/cymbal then mix it up into one output?

Comment: or the samples themselves? then, are they still controllable enough?

Comment: I mix the sample data myself into one single output stereo sample and play that over a single audio output stream.     What do you mean with "controllable"?  I guess that totally depends on how you do the mixing. I suggest looking into playing separate output streams via pyaudio first

Comment: with controllable i mean can i do the mixing realtime with flexible timed drum hits. for now i think it is possible but much harder than separated audio streams and the audio streams solution sounds better for this problem i think.

Comment: Well yeah it's not easy. I've programmed it as an exercise and to learn a bit more myself about audio manipulation in Python, you can take a look if you want perhaps it helps https://github.com/irmen/synthesizer#how-the-track-mixer-works

Comment: Since stream to actual device is single, you can try `interleaving` the audio using `pydub`. Basically overlay files such that longest on plays the last. Or you can make chunks using `pydub` and combine them before playing.